# Require not defined error: Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, karma-jasmine

I am testing nodejs API and I included file in karma.config.js
I got the following error: Require not defined. 
Then as per the suggestions given in other posts I added browserify to that file, but now I am getting different error.

```
 ` files: [
        'poc/app/api.js',       // file where there is require statements
        'tests/sample.test.js'  // my test file
    ],
   preprocessors: {

          'poc/app/api.js':['browserify']  

      },`
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
Please let me know how to resolve this.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

This error should also include a file name and line number. Since you didn't include that information or the source code, the only advice that can be given here is to check that line of that file, see what can be undefined, track how it got there, where it should be defined but is not and fix the problems that responsible for that.

Comment: I am running from webstorm. It points to temp location. Please see the details below:                                                                                                     
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Naveen/AppData/Local/Temp/2e5944d773969e64006240592d1530bc.browserify?1e534fd38d40357c60b816bbebc25fd57e081681:47112